# Django - Add CSS Class to SplitDateTimeWidget?

Tags: django, forms

I have used the SplitDateTimeWidget to override a field in my model form.
Is there a way for to assign css classes to the individual fields created by this?

```
widgets = {
              'my_field': SplitDateTimeWidget(),
                }
```

Any advice appreciated.

After I tried your code Brandon:

If I try it without passing attrs I get: 
'NoneType' object is not iterable

for the line attrs_dict = dict(attrs).

If I do include attrs, I get: 
'tuple' object has no attribute 'copy'

at /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/forms/widgets.py in **init**, line 147

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can pass in attrs={'class' : 'your_class'}, but it will apply the class to both the DateInput and TimeInput.

If you're needing to add a different class to both fields, you'll probably need to extend SplitDateTimeWidget, override the init.

```
class MySplitDateTimeWidget(SplitDateTimeWidget):
    def __init__(self, attrs=None, date_format=None, time_format=None):
        date_class = attrs.pop('date_class')
        time_class = attrs.pop('time_class')

        widgets = (DateInput(attrs={'class' : date_class}, format=date_format),
               TimeInput(attrs={'class' : time_class}, format=time_format))
        super(SplitDateTimeWidget, self).__init__(widgets, attrs)

#forms.py

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    test_field = forms.DateTimeField(widget=MySplitDateTimeWidget(attrs={'date_class' : 'foo', 'time_class' : 'bar'}))
```

I've tested this in Django 1.3, which will output the following html when using that widget on a forms.DateTimeField called 'test_field':

```
<label for="id_test_field_0">Test field:</label>
<input id="id_test_field_0" class="foo" type="text" name="test_field_0">
<input id="id_test_field_1" class="bar" type="text" name="test_field_1">
```

I've tried various ways to copy the attrs that come in to preserve any other params that might be there, but I'm running into errors, and unfortunately I've run out of time for today. This should get you going, but will only allow you to modify the class attr of the fields.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your help.  I've tried using this but I get the following error: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'copy'

Comment: I updated my code sample to convert attrs into a dict. Please give that a try.

Comment: Thanks again, I've written a response in the original question, the comment box didn't allow for proper formatting.

Comment: Let me see if I can get a working sample going for you and I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Starting in Django 2.0 SplitDateTimeWidget supports time_attrs and date_attrs parameters.

From the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/widgets/#splitdatetimewidget):

> Similar to Widget.attrs. A
>   dictionary containing HTML attributes to be set on the rendered
>   DateInput and TimeInput widgets, respectively. If these attributes
>   aren’t set, Widget.attrs is used instead.

So you would use them something like the following:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    test_field = forms.DateTimeField(widget=SplitDateTimeWidget(date_attrs={'class' : 'foo'}, time_attrs={'class' : 'bar'}))
```